# new Vaadin on new Netbeans -- the basic dependencies

Tags: maven, netbeans, vaadin

I'm getting the following error when i compile the widgetset. I'm using Vaadin 7.3.8 on Netbeans 8.0.2. :

```
> cd C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-ui; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_20" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" vaadin:compile\""
Scanning for projects...

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Building AVaad - AVaad-ui 1.0-SNAPSHOT
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> vaadin-maven-plugin:7.3.7:compile (default-cli) @ AVaad-ui >>>

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ AVaad-ui ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-ui\src\main\resources

<<< vaadin-maven-plugin:7.3.7:compile (default-cli) @ AVaad-ui <<<
> The POM for com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.727s
Finished at: Wed Jan 14 16:22:41 EST 2015
Final Memory: 8M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Failed to execute goal on project AVaad-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:AVaad-ui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I've only added the add-on dependencies to `pom.xml` haven't changed anything on `pom.xml` or elsewhere since i installed the Vaadin plug-in.

What's missing in my setup?

Is this a version problem -- if i installed an earlier Vaadin version -- like 7.1. .., would i end up with the same thing?

Netbeans 8 has been around for a file and i've been happily using it.

TIA.

//==========================================

EDIT:

What i'm getting after i clean&build the project in Netbeans is as follows:

```
> cd C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-ui; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_20" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" clean install\""
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building AVaad - AVaad-ui 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> Downloading: http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> Downloading: http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> The POM for com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
> Downloading: http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    
> Downloading: http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/mycompany/AVaad-widgetset/1.0-SNAPSHOT/AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.409s
Finished at: Thu Jan 15 09:39:19 EST 2015
Final Memory: 10M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Failed to execute goal on project AVaad-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:AVaad-ui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in vaadin-addons (http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons) -> [Help 1]

> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: It complains that it cannot find the com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT dependency. What's your project structure?

Comment: what do you mean by prj structure? i haven't touched anything-- except those i mentioned in the Q: the dependency tags in pom for and the lisence for charts. nothing elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining it cannot find dependency `com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT` from your Maven repository.

You need to say `mvn clean install` for your AVaad-widgetset project which is most likely located in the `C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-widgetset` directory. This command will install the dependency to your local maven repository.

Comment: only pom.xml & the src directory in C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-widgetset.

Comment: That's true. Maven is an external tool (the `mvn` command). You most likely can do the same thing from Netbean's UI but I don't have experience about netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

You have to generate netbeans in the following order:

1. parent
2. widgetset
3. production
4. UI