# Vaadin dependencies -- Vaadin 7.3.8, Netbeans 8

Tags: maven, netbeans, vaadin

I'm getting the following error when i attempt to build the Vaadin project on Netbeans.

> Failed to execute goal on project AVaad-ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:AVaad-ui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 (provided), com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.3.8 (compile), com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar:7.3.7 (compile), com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar:7.3.8 (compile), com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.0.CR1 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mycompany:AVaad-widgetset:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.mycompany:AVaad:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The dependencies are "supposedly" there:

For vaadin-server for instance;

`vaadin-server-7.3.8.jar` is listed in the `Dependencies` directory of the project.

And this is what the `pom.xml` for that dependency looks like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

What's missing here?

TIA.

//===========================

**EDIT:**

I'm getting this after running `mvn clean install` as suggested in [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952961/new-vaadin-on-new-netbeans-the-basic-dependencies).

`mvn clean install` seems to be doing what it's supposed to be doing -- the very last lines out of this run are as follows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ AVaad-widgetset ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-widgetset\target\AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\H\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\AVaad-widgetset\1.0-SNAPSHOT\AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-widgetset\pom.xml to C:\Users\H\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\AVaad-widgetset\1.0-SNAPSHOT\AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\H\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AVaad\AVaad-widgetset\target\AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to C:\Users\H\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\AVaad-widgetset\1.0-SNAPSHOT\AVaad-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.789 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-16T10:45:00-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

//=========================

**EDIT - 2:**

Am i supposed to put anything for the repositories into the `pom` file?

The repositories tag of my pom currently looks like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "maven central" repository is there by default, defined by ["super pom"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html). If you need just basic java libraries and some Vaadin add-ons, those repositories are enough.

I assume all other issues were already resolved?